# Incrementing a column for each rows from two queries

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have two queries that give respectively the number of working unit bought, and the number of working unit consumed by a client.

I am working on a SQL Server 2014

The WUBought query returns something like this example :

```
Customer    Year    Month   UnitBought
Cust1       2015    6       50
Cust2       2014    7       100
Cust1       2013    10      30
Cust3       2015    2       40
```

The other query returns the number that were consumed by a client :

```
Customer    Year    Month   UnitConsumed
Cust1       2015    2       6
Cust1       2015    5       20
Cust2       2015    3       8
Cust1       2015    4       3
Cust3       2015    2       10
```

What I am basically trying to do, is a sum of what has been bought for every month, minus what has been consumed. Here is an example of what I want as a result for the first six months for Cust1 :

```
Customer    Year    Month   Remaining
Cust1       2015    1       30
Cust1       2015    2       24
Cust2       2015    3       24
Cust1       2015    4       21
Cust3       2015    5       1
Cust3       2015    6       51
```

The query that returns the WU bought with a UNION ALL from a table that lists every month, to get each month even if there is no value :

```
SELECT Customer, [Year], [Month], SUM(UOBought) AS UORest
    FROM WU_Bought
    GROUP BY [Customer], [PurchaseDate]
UNION ALL
SELECT '' AS Customer, [Year], [Month], '' AS UORest
    FROM  Months
    GROUP BY [Year], [Month]
```

Here is the query that sums every bought unit every month, with the same union statement :

```
SELECT Customer, [Year], [Month], SUM(TotalConsumed) * -1 AS UORest
    FROM WUConsumed
    GROUP BY Customer, Year, Month
UNION ALL
SELECT '' AS Customer, [Year], [Month], '' AS UORest
    FROM EveryMonths
    GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Right now I think I must adjust the first one, forcing it to keep the previous sum, but I am not sure how I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working.

What I did was really "simple", using a SQL Server feature, available since 2012 : 
ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

[Here is a pretty clear article](http://stevestedman.com/2012/03/transact-sql-over-clause-rows-unbounded-preceding-or-following/) about this feature.

I created an other view grouping the results from the queries about consumed and bought units with a UNION ALL clause, called "WU_Closing_View", then used the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING within it :

```
SELECT Customer, Year, Month, SUM(Closing) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Year, Month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Closing
    FROM WU_Closing_View
    GROUP BY Customer, Year, Month, Closing
UNION ALL
SELECT     '' AS Customer, Year, Month, '' AS Sum_bought
    FROM         Months
    GROUP BY Year, Month
    ORDER BY Customer, Year, Month
```

Note that I used `PARTITION BY`, in order to sum by client. Because I wanted to show every month in a SSRS matrix, I added a "UNION ALL" pointing to a table that has every year and month on it for an empty client, from 2010 to 2017. But it is optional if you don't need the evolution for every month.

There may be an easier way, but that's the one I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT b.customer_id, b.year, b.month, SUM(b.units_bought) AS units_bought, ISNULL(c.units_consumed,0) AS units_consumed, SUM(b.units_bought) - ISNULL(c.units_consumed,0) AS units_remaining
    FROM Bought b
    LEFT JOIN Consumed c
        ON b.customer_id = c.customer_id AND b.year = c.year AND b.month = c.month
GROUP BY b.customer_id, b.year, b.month
```

Comment: Namrehs, I had to add c.units_consumed to the group by clause, because it gave me an error. I have some more problems with this query : somehow, it doesn't keep the previous units bought, I think, and only gives me the result for a month where the client bought more units.